# How to exclude weak protocols (ciphers suits) from the Netty SSLContext?

Tags: ssl, netty, tls1.0, tls1.1

On my Netty server, I need to exclude TLS_1.0 and TLS_1.1 protocols. However, seems like Netty `SslContextBuilder` doesn't allow to exclude specific suits.

Current code is used to build a SSL context:

```
SslContextBuilder.forServer(serverCert, serverKey, serverPass)
                .sslProvider(sslProvider)
                .build();
```

`SslContextBuilder` has `ciphers()` method, but it's not clear how to exclude specific ciphers for the TLS_1.0 and TLS_1.1.

Is there any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would just specify the protocols you want to support:

```
SslContextBuilder.forServer(serverCert, serverKey, serverPass)
                .sslProvider(sslProvider).protocols(...)
```

So only include TLSv1.2 and TLSv1.3 here.

Another possibility would be to specify your custom `CipherSuiteFilter` which filters out ciphers you don't want to support.