# Way to block use of TLS 1.0/1.1 when using Ktor/Netty

Tags: kotlin, netty, ktor

I'm currently using Ktor Server 1.6.x along with Netty and trying to block use of TLS 1.0 and 1.1.  If using Netty on it's own it looks like this could be achieved something like approach in [How to exclude weak protocols (ciphers suits) from the Netty SSLContext?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65680170/how-to-exclude-weak-protocols-ciphers-suits-from-the-netty-sslcontext) but when using with Ktor it doesn't look like way to customise for example `SslContextBuilder`.  Has anyone come across way to do this?

Update:
Got confirmation that this was not currently possible....created following feature request https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-4587/